# Connection switching to support multiple databases is not working in Rails 6.0.0.beta3 version

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-6

I have read the documentation about MultiDb connection switching of Rails 6.0.0.beta3 and implemented this way:

**database.yml**

```
default: &default
adapter: mysql2
encoding: utf8mb4
pool: <%= ENV.fetch("RAILS_MAX_THREADS") { 5 } %>
username: root
password: root
socket: /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock

development:
  main:
    <<: *default
    database: r6_multidb_development

  main_replica:
    <<: *default
    database: r6_multidb_development_copy
    replica: true
```

**Article Model**

```
class Article < ApplicationRecord
  connect_to database: { writing: :main, reading: :main_replica }
end
```

Both the databases r6_multidb_development and r6_multidb_development_copy have different records, i was expecting when record is created records should inserted on r6_multidb_development Database and when retrieving record it should from r6_multidb_development_copy database. But in both cases when record is inserted and retrieved it is happening from main configuration that is r6_multidb_development database.

I believe write to the database should happen from r6_multidb_development and read should happen from r6_multidb_development_copy. I would appreciate if anybody figure out this issue.

Answer (score 1):

Add following options to your environment config:

```
config.active_record.database_selector = { delay: 2.seconds }
config.active_record.database_resolver = ActiveRecord::Middleware::DatabaseSelector::Resolver
config.active_record.database_resolver_context = ActiveRecord::Middleware::DatabaseSelector::Resolver::Session
```